# Change the color of a seekbar on onProgressChanged

Tags: android, colors, seekbar

I have custom  seekbar and I can change the the color in the onProgressChanged by setting a new progress drawable:

```
seek.setProgressDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar_bg1));
```

But I would like a seekbar which has a solid color from green to red depending on the progress.
Is there a way to use something like a gradient color so I don't need to create like 100 drawables this?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
  <shape>
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
  </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/progressshape">
<clip>
  <shape>
    <solid android:color="@color/custom_yellow" />
  </shape>
</clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

**For those who are interested in the solution. I use the following code:**

this method to set the color:

```
public void setProgressBarColor(int newColor){ 
  LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) getProgressDrawable();
  ClipDrawable d1 = (ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progressshape);
  d1.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

and in the onProgressChanged:

```
 if(progress <= 50){
                seek.setProgressBarColor(Color.rgb( 255 - (255/100 * (100 - progress*2)), 255, 0));
 }else{
                seek.setProgressBarColor(Color.rgb( 255, 255 - (255/100 * (progress - 50)*2), 0));
 }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I do something like this using this method:

```
public void setProgressBarColor(ProgressBar progressBar, int newColor){ 
    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
    ClipDrawable d1 = (ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progressshape);
    d1.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

}
```

Then, when you update the progress, you just have to change the desired color.

Comment: How can I access the R.id.progressshape that is used by default?

Comment: "android.R.id.progress" via code or "@android:id/progress" via xml (don't know if this was what you asked for though)

Comment: This worked for me until Android 5.0, where getProgressDrawable() returns a StateListDrawable instead of a Drawable, and throws a ClassCastException. I've reported this as a bug, and included a workaround in the bug report: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82062

Answer (score 5):

Use this :

```
bar.setProgressDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.rgb( red, green, blue)));
```

Change the red,green,blue with progress change.

Comment: thnx for trying to help, but the progress drawable need to like above (a layer-list with a shape and a clip).. Do you know how i can create this drawable programmatically or edit the clip shape color in runtime?