# Change Intensity of blue colour as the seekbar progress is changed

Tags: android

I have seekbar with background colour blue andI want to change the intensity of blue colour as the seekbar progress is changed.As i m a beginner so am not able to understand,can anyone please help me with the code.

Comment: this could help you.. progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);

Comment: I want to change the intensity of blue color(the thumb is of blue colour) as we move the thumb of the seekbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837843/change-the-color-of-a-seekbar-on-onprogresschanged

Comment: I have used this code previously but dont know it is not recognizing getProgressDrawable() and from where the clipdrawable id is taken

Comment: it may be drawable shape defined in drawable folder..

Comment: can you plz elaborate i m not able to understand

Answer (score 0):

Try below link it might be helpful to you

[How can you dynamically update the color of a SeekBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315792/how-can-you-dynamically-update-the-color-of-a-seekbar) √

[Change the color of a seekbar on onProgressChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9837843/change-the-color-of-a-seekbar-on-onprogresschanged)

Or you can create custom seekbar to implement the same